# Get actual incoming IP from behind NAT

Tags: php, apache

Ubuntu 14.04 Apache 2.4 PHP

`$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]` always returns the IP of my router. Is there a way to get the actual incoming IP?

Comment: Sometimes the NAT/proxy device will add a `X-Forwarded-For` header. You can look in `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']`.

Comment: `$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]` might work on your server but will actually raise an `E_NOTICE` that `REMOTE_ADDR` is not defined, and that it will assume the string `'REMOTE_ADDR'` instead. Don't rely on this code, but use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` (note the single quotes) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Used isset($_SERVER[]) to test for 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR' 'HTTP_REFFER' and 'REMOTE ADDR' and used whichever was available. If none available used default processing